# Why isn't JavaScript for loop incrementing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace the `<li>` with 1. 2. 3. respectively.  I managed to change the `<li>` to a number, but that number is `0`.  The loop doesn't want to work.  To be honest, this method may be impossible.

**Take a look at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxSnR/3/) if you'd like.**

This is my `function(){...}` :

```
function doIt(){

        var input = document.getElementById("input");
        var li = /<li>/; // match opening li
        var liB = /<\/li>/; // match closing li
        var numberOfItems = input.value.match(li).length; // number of lis that occur


        for(var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
            insertNumber(i); // execute insertNumber function w/ parameter of incremented i 
        }

        function insertNumber(number){
            input.value = input.value.replace(li, number + "." + " ").replace(liB, "");
        }


    }
```

I understand the `insertNumber(){...}` function **is not** necessary.

Comment: `numberOfItems` is undefined.

Comment: In your first loop you replace ALL `<li>`s (with 0)... in your 2nd there is nothing left to replace. Maybe remove the `gi` from your regex.

Comment: in this context of the code posted on stackoverflow it is undefined.

Comment: Like @christian314159 said, after the first iteration there are no more `<li>` in the text. Some debugging code would reveal it to you. And please put a full code example in the question instead of just linking.

Comment: Consider an approach [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/CxSnR/6/). It's a bit simpler.

Comment: @cookiemonster Thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for.  I never knew you could put functions within methods like that!

Comment: The `.replace()` method specifically allows a function as the second argument. Its return value becomes the replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an alternative method](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/D8Yah/1/), turning your HTML textarea contents into DOM elements that jQuery can manipulate and managing them that way:

```
function doIt() {
    var $domElements = $.parseHTML( $('#input').val().trim() ),
        output = [],
        i = 1;
    $.each($domElements, function(index, element) {
        if($(this).text().trim() != '') {
            output.push( i + '. ' + $(this).text().trim() );
            i++;
        }
    });
    $('#input').val(output.join('\n'));
}
```

Comment: Incidentally you can also do `output.push(i++ + '....')` and remove the extra line, but this is amusingly difficult to read

Comment: That works, thanks!  I really appreciate the help, and I will definitely look back at this later.  I want to use a raw JavaScript approach, because I feel that I should have full comprehension of a language before diving into a library of it.  I'm going to use @cookiemonster 's [method](http://jsfiddle.net/CxSnR/8/).